# Регулярное выражение - спецсимволы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d*([t][\\^\\*\\.\\+]*?[e][s][t])\\b", 
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(filterText("test")); // +
        System.out.println(filterText("t.est")); // +
        System.out.println(filterText("t*est"));
        System.out.println(filterText("t^est"));
        System.out.println(filterText("t+est"));
    }
    
    public static String filterText(String text) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String word = matcher.group(0);
            text = text.replaceAll(word, word.replaceAll(".", "*"));
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Вывод: 
**** 
***** 
t****** 
t^est 
t+est 
Не работает экранирование спец. символов: **^*+**

Comment: Непонятно, в чём вопрос. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не там ищете. Регулярное выражение правильно отрабатывает. Это можно проверить, попробовав что-нибудь вывести в консоль в блоке `while`. Соответственно, проблема в:

```
String word = matcher.group(0);
text = text.replaceAll(word, word.replaceAll(".", "*"));
```

Кстати, внутри `[]` не нужно экранировать `+.*`. `^` тоже можно не экранировать, если переместить с нулевого значения. `"\\b\\d*([t][+^*.]?[e][s][t])\\b"` вполне отрабатывает.

Comment: Спасибо, заменил replaceAll на replace, все заработало как нужно.